# Retrieve text from a large file using a smaller matching header

Tags: files, text

I need to extract the text between two headers, if the first one matches with a source file for lookup the headers to search, example:

```
&Header1

1231241241313124123213123214124123213213124124123123212

1231231231231231231231231231232131242141241241231325552

2132141241232132132132141251232132142142132132132142412

&Header2

1231241241313124123213123214124123213213124124123123212

2132141241232132132132141251232132142142132132132142412

&Header3

1231241241313124123213123214124123213213124124123123212

1231231231231231231231231231232131242141241241231325552

213214124123213213213214125123213214
```

And my source file:

```
&Header1

&Header3
```

So only retrieve header1 and 3 with the number information bellow.

Comment: are these header exiting only once in the file or can there be multiple instances ? And in either case, will there be an unmatched header. Like, for instance, in the given example, would there be a `&Header1` without a matching `&Header3` or vice-versa?

Comment: Those headers are unique in the big file, to be precisely I have 255k headers/labels

Comment: If you are using this in a two pass fashion,  pass 1 could split at the `header` lines, and make a file in a temporary directory. named for that header string, and containing the data for that header.  During pass 2, your processor would treat a detected header call as 'get data in file defined by header'. Using the filesystem in a db sort of fashion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startheader=$(head -1 sourcefile)
endheader=$(tail -1 sourcefile)

# above lines assume your sourcefile has two lines in it and 
# each line contains the starting header and ending header

startlinenumber=$(grep -n "${startheader}" datafile|cut -d: -f1)
endlinenumber=$(grep -n "${endheader}" datafile|cut -d: -f1)

sed -n -e "${startlinenumber},${endlinenumber}p" datafile
```

I am pretty sure, there is a more elaborate way of doing this with either `awk` or `perl` or maybe a single liner `sed` command but I just wanted to give you the logic explicitly. You can play with it and make it fit to your needs.